# Kann man "blättern" auch ohne Präfix oder Präposition benutzen?

Tags: grammar, prefix

> Ich blättere die Seiten des Buches von 1 bis 20 durch.

Wird der Satz noch Sinn ergeben, wenn die Vorsilbe "durch" weggelassen ist:

> Ich blättere die Seiten des Buches von 1 bis 20 (durch).

Comment: Nein, Du kannst nicht „eine Seite blättern“.

Comment: Man kann aber in einem Buch blättern.

Comment: Also wenn die Vorsilbe ausgelassen ist, ändert die Bedeutung des Satzes.

Comment: Ja, von mit Bedeutung zu ohne Bedeutung.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Du kannst die Seiten eines Buches nicht einfach "blättern". Du kannst entweder eine Seite "umblättern" oder das Buch "durchblättern".

Du brauchst das "durch":

> Ich blättere die Seiten des Buches von 1 bis 20 durch.
>   Ich durchblättere die Seiten des Buches von 1 bis 20.

Besser wäre jedoch:

> Ich blättere die Seiten 1-20 des Buches durch.

Comment: Oder `Ich blättere durch die Seiten (1-20) des Buches./ durch die Buchseiten (1-20).`

Answer (score 4):

"Blättern" cannot take a direct object. But it can very well take prepositional ones.  It means ... "to turn pages"

> Ich blättere in einem Magazin.
>
> Ich blättere durch alte Fotoalben.
>
> Wie blättere ich beim Kindle?

"Durchblättern" needs a direct object. You can't use it without one

> Ich blättere das Fotoalbum durch.

So.. the answer is YES. Only the grammar is different.

Comment: Ich blätterte ihm 25 Euro in kleinen Scheinen hin.

Comment: @userunknown... da ist das Verb "hinblättern" und nicht "blättern"... genauso kann man über "über/ent/ver/um/zurück/weiterblättern" reden. ar aber hier nicht gefragt.