# Partizip 2 "ge" Infix oder Präfix

Tags: single-word-request, prefix, anglicism, participle

## Frage

Ich suche Verben deren Partizip 2 folgendermaßen aussieht: `[Präfix]ge[Basis]`

Wobei kein Verb existiert dessen Partizip 2 `ge[Basis]` ist.

Die Wortexistenz soll dabei einem Wörterbuch, vorzugsweise dem Duden entnommen werden.
Weder Präfix noch das Verb selber sollen dabei anglizismen sein. Damit fällt `Downgeloaded` weg.
Und das "ge" soll aus der Partizipbildung kommen, also `[ausgebag]ge[rt]` zählt nicht.

## Hintergrund

Es geht um das Wort ["updaten"](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/updaten). Insbesondere ging es um die Frage ob das Partizip 2 nun "upgedatet" (wie im Duden) oder "geupdatet" ist.

Ein Argument lautet:

> "daten" ist kein eigenständiges Wort und demnach ist "up" kein Präfix. Somit ist das Gesamtwort "updaten" der Stamm.

Mit dem Resultat:

> Das Partizip 2 muss "geupdatet" lauten.

Dass "daten" kein Wort sei, bezieht sich darauf, dass es kein solches Verb im Duden gibt. Es gibt zwar das Substantiv [Daten](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Dating). Dies ist aber ungültig, ist ja kein Verb.

Nun suche ich Beispiele, welche ähnlichen konstruiert sind aber dennoch als "eindeutig Deutsch" einzuordnen wären. Bei allem was mir einfällt ist der Stamm auch wieder ein gültiges Wort. Es geht also bei der eigentlichen Frage nicht um die "richtige Schreibweise" sondern nur darum, ob das Argument gültig sein kann (es wird kein Gegenbeispiel gefunden) oder nicht (Konstruktiver Beweis durch Gegenbeispiel).

Natürlich nehme ich auch weitere Argumente für oder wider die Schreibweisen. Aber das ist nicht der zentrale Aspekt der Frage.

---

Ich möchte nochmal betonen, dass es eigentlich um die ganz oben aufgeführte Frage geht, NICHT um Fragen wie "welche Form ist richtig", "sollte man nicht lieber 'aktualisiert' oder ähnliches verwenden" oder gar "Sollte man wieder die Todesstrafe einführen für Leute, welche Anglizismismen verwenden."
Es geht auch nicht um Sprachgefühl oder Klang.

---

Eine nicht gültige Option wäre ["blättern"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9907/kann-man-bl%c3%a4ttern-auch-ohne-pr%c3%a4fix-oder-pr%c3%a4position-benutzen). Das steht [so im Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/blaettern).

Comment: Alle unregelmäßigen Verben wie *abgenommen*?

Comment: Ist das etwa ein Scrabble-Streitfall? Oder warum ist nur der Duden erlaubt?

Comment: @Björก้้้้้้้้้้้้้้Friedrich mmmh, die Formulierung des Problems ist nicht wirklich formal. Ich hoffe, dass quasi "verstanden" wird, was ist suche (Mir fehlt das Wissen dazu). Ich habe Formulierung mal angepasst. Demnach funktioniert "abgenommen" dann auch nicht.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach nicht wirklich. Aber ist in etwa gleich unwichtig.

Answer (score 3):

»Wracken« finde ich nirgends als Verb verzeichnet, also müsste »abwracken« passen?

Comment: Danke. Sehr kreativ.

Comment: Wracken gibt es schon, allerdings fällt mir auch kein direktes Beispiel ein, wo es ohne entsprechende Präfix/Suffix-Zusätze für sich allein steht. Siehe das eher umgangssprachliche hinwracken oder eben abwracken.

Answer (score 3):

Dem gesuchten Muster entsprechen einige Verben, bei denen die Basis ein Nomen (oder Adjektiv) ist:

- abdachen
- anfeinden
- beipflichten
- eindeutschen
- umgarnen
- zusammenrotten

Als Alternative solche, bei denen die Basis ungebräuchlich geworden ist (wobei *ungebräuchlich* natürlich Spielraum läßt).

- einbleuen (*neue Rechtschreibung:* einbläuen; von ahd. *bliuwan*, nicht *blâo*)<sup>[1](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/An_Etymological_Dictionary_of_the_German_Language/bl%C3%A4uen)</sup>
- ausmergeln, abmergeln
- aufwiegeln, abwiegeln

Die Beispiele mit *-mergeln* könnte man auch in die erste Gruppe stellen; aber die Herkunft als Ableitung von *Mark* (wie in *Knochenmark*) ist nicht mehr erkennbar.<sup>[2](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/An_Etymological_Dictionary_of_the_German_Language/Annotated/mergeln)</sup>

Comment: Super. Schon peinlich, dass mir nichts eingefallen ist. Auch sehr schön, dass auf die Gesetzmäßigkeit (Substantiv als Basis/Ungebräuchliche Basis) hingeswiesen wurde.

Answer (score 2):

Was man als "richtig" ansieht, ist am Ende Geschmacksache.<sup>[1]</sup> Dass sich in einer Sprache Regularitäten antreffen lassen, heißt noch nicht, dass eine Abweichung von einer solchen Regularität "falsch" ist.

Bei Fremdworten gibt es oft eine Phase, in der verschiedene Varianten koexistieren. Mitunter stabilsiert sich mit der Zeit eine bestimmte Gebrauchsweise, mitunter auch nicht. Gegenwärtig sind sowohl *upgedatet* als auch *geupdatet* in Gebrauch und daher auch "richtig".

Vielleicht ist es sinnvoller, zu analysieren, welche Konzepte dem jeweiligen Gebrauch zugrunde liegen:

## upgedatet

In *upgedatet* wird das englische Präfix *up-* als solches erkannt und verstanden. *upgedatet* ist damit die Analogiebildung zum englischen Partizip: Auch wenn das englische Verb als solches nicht im Deutschen Wortschatz vorhanden wäre, wird es doch als eigene Einheit konzipiert. Allerdings würde ich der Aussage widersprechen, dass *daten* kein deutsches Verb sei.

> Seit wann datest du ihn?

ist in meinen Augen ein völlig normaler deutscher Satz. Aber man kann berechtigterweise einwenden, dass das ein anderes Verb ist, als das *daten* in *updaten*.

Solche Analogiebildungen hat es in der Vergangenheit schon öfter gegeben. So werden etwa die Partizipien der auf *-ieren* endenden Verben in Analogie zur Partizipbildung in der (romanischen) Herkunftssprache gebildet:

- *reüssiert* (von frz. *reussir*, Partizip: *reussi*) statt **gereüssiert*
- *rekapituliert* (von lat. *recapitulare*) statt **gerekapituliert*
- usw. usf.

Ganz analog ist es bei dem Partizip *downgeloadet* von *downloaden*.

## geupdatet

Verwendet man *geupdatet*, wird das Verb *updaten* als eine Einheit aufgefasst. Bei Menschen, die kein oder wenig Englisch sprechen, würde man vermuten, dass sie eher zu dieser Variante tendieren. Vielleicht ist das Verb
[*schanghaien*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanghaien) mit dem Partizip *geschanghait* ein analoges Beispiel:<sup>[2]</sup> Auch wenn *shang* im Chinesischen grammatisch als Vorsilbe aufgefasst werden könnte, so wird doch *Shanghai* im Deutschen als untrennbare Einheit aufgefasst.

---

[1] Siehe auch: [Normative Fragen](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/normative-fragen)
[2] Ob die Analogie gut ist, kann ich nicht so gut  beurteilen, da ich das Chinesische nicht beherrsche.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Antowort. Sie enthält einige interessante Punkte, die wir nicht bedacht hatten. Da mir klar war, dass sich "normative" Fragen schlecht beantworten lassen, hatte ich versucht eine möglich formale Anforderung zu stellen. In diesem Sinne kann ich diese Antwort aber nicht akzeptieren (also das grüne Häkchen da setzen). Ich habe die Frage nochmals überarbeitet. Vielleicht findet sich ja noch ein solches Wort. [wahrscheinlich nicht]

Comment: @Burdui Ja, ich sehe jetzt auch, dass die Antwort nicht ganz zur Frage passt. Mir war die Frage nicht richtig klar, und ich habe mich wohl auf einen falschen Aspekt fokussiert. Ich lasse die Antwort dennoch stehen, vielleicht ist es ja für zuküntige Leser\*innen von Belang.

Comment: Ich bin selber unentschlossen, eine Aussage dazu zu machen, ob das tatsächlich in die Antwort hineingehört - aber ich fände es schon interessant, zu wissen, ob diejenigen, die "upgedatet" und "downgeloadet" verwenden (und somit *up* und *down* als trennbaren Präfix behandeln), auch folgerichtig Sätze à la "Ich date das Programm up." und "Ich loade die Datei down." bilden.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ja, guter Punkt!

Comment: @O.R.Mapper ich kann nur für mich sprechen. Solche Konstruktionen kommen tatsächlich vor, also zumindest das "Ich date das Programm up.". Selbstredend war ich im Lager "upgedated". Ganz interessant ist auch, dass ich beim schreiben dieses Kommentars realisiert habe, dass ich intuitiv die englische past participle Form mit "ed" verwende.

Answer (score 2):

Die Frage läuft darauf hinaus, ob es trennbare Verben gibt, bei denen das Stammverb nicht Teil des deutschen Wortschatzes ist.

Ich habe diese Beispiele gefunden:

> abbeeren, abdachen, abflauen, abmatten, abplatten, abschlaffen, abschotten, abschranken, abspecken, abstatten, abwracken, abzweigen, anfeinden, anfreunden, anrauen, anschuldigen, aufbahren, aufgleisen, aufklaren, aufrauen, ausbeinen, ausbüchsen, ausbuchten, ausixen, ausknocken, ausschalen, aussöhnen, ausstatten, einbuchten, eindellen, eindosen, einheimsen, einpfarren, einrexen, einsargen, einschalen, eintüten, nachahmen, zumüllen